# Show template path in admin panel magento

Tags: magento

I am working with magento admin panel, I want to on template path as like we do for front end, I tried it by installed an extention, but its not working.Please let me know how can I do that ?

Comment: accept one of the given answers that you find helpful. It will be useful to others also

Answer (score 7):

Goto

> app > code > core > Mage > core > etc > system.xml

**Line 512**

you can see this

```
<template_hints translate="label">
      <label>Template Path Hints</label>
      <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
      <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
      <sort_order>20</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</template_hints>
```

Change the `<show_in_default>` to **1** and save.

Then goto admin panel `system > configuration > developer > Debug` Enable path hint.

Cheers

Comment: You have small error in path specified. It should be `app > code > core > Mage > core > etc > system.xml`

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
       VALUES ('websites', '0', 'dev/debug/template_hints', '1');
```

Run the following query:

To Enable:

```
UPDATE core_config_data set value = 1 where scope = 'default' and scope_id = 0 and path ='dev/debug/template_hints'
```

To Disable:

```
UPDATE core_config_data set value = 0 where scope = 'default' and scope_id = 0 and path ='dev/debug/template_hints'
```

Delete the record when you are done with or set value 0 as described above . Do not forget to remove the cache

Comment: Then if we want to turn OFF the hints again do we need to touch the same table in DB??

Answer (score 0):

Run this query in your database

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0,  'dev/debug/template_hints', 1),('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this query:

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints', 1), ('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks', 1);
```

Now, to remove these template paths from Admin Panel, just fire these two queries:

```
delete from core_config_data where scope='default' and scope_id=0 and path='dev/debug/template_hints_blocks' and value=1
```

and

```
delete from core_config_data where scope='default' and scope_id=0 and path='dev/debug/template_hints' and value=1
```

and remove cache insert query and delete query also.