# Magento How to Add template path hint for admin/back-end

Tags: magento

I want to enable template path hints in admin panel. I know how to do it for the front end, but for back end?? I actually want to edit the admin panel .

Thanks in advance..

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398645/show-template-path-in-admin-panel-magento/22398762#22398762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES this is woriking!!

```
 INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
   VALUES ('websites', '0', 'dev/debug/template_hints', '1');
```