# Is it possible to change the price in the shopping cart in magento?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, magento

I have modified the function under **\magento\js\varien\product.js** in order to satisfy my client's requirement. It works fine, the discount will apply due to the users information from our database. 
[image]

But when the customer add an item to cart, it only shows the original price which is $549.47 in this example.

[image]

How can i insert the discounted price into the unit price and subtotal section? Which file should i modify in order to achieve this?

**Here's part of my javascript codes(\magento\js\varien\product.js) which generate the discounted price:**

```
var subPrice = 0; //is the price inside the option
            var subPriceincludeTax = 0;
            var discountRate = discountRateUrl; //discount base on database
            var price = priceUrl;//get the product price
            var discountedPrice = price*discountRate; // price * ourdiscount
            //var discountedSubPrice = subPrice*((100-test)/100); // custom option addition price * ourdiscounted prices
            //console.log(discountedPrice); //display the prices as int
            //console.log(discountedSubPrice);
            //console.log(test);
            Object.values(this.customPrices).each(function(el){
                if (el.excludeTax && el.includeTax) {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.excludeTax); // use the var factor && this will affect the price when changing option *important
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.includeTax);

                } else {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.price);
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.price);

                }
                var finalprice = (subPrice*discountRate+discountedPrice);//checking if getting the php
                var fomattedprice = finalprice.toFixed(2); //Convert a number into a string, keeping only two decimals
                console.log(finalprice); //tester of the final prices
                console.log(discountRate);//tester discount rate in string
                document.getElementById("finalprice").innerHTML = "<small>Your price is </small>"+ "$" + fomattedprice + "*" +"<br/><small><em>*Discount will be applied during check out</em></small>";
          });
```

You can ignore these bunch of codes, i just want to know where should i pass my `document.getElementById("finalprice");` result in order to show the discounted price.

Please leave a comment if there's something unclear, also do feel free to edit my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify

> frontend/default/your_theme/template/checkout/item/default.phtml

This file is responsible for displaying the products and their information in the cart. Here you can make the changes to see the desired output.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have mine in \frontend\your_theme\default\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phml is this the same file you mention? By the way i assume modifying this file will not change the invoice, yea? Can you give me the file name about the invoice as well please? Thanks, aton1004. :)

Comment: Yes it is the same file.No this will not change the invoice.You can see the file path by enabling the template path hint for admin panel please care to see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398645/show-template-path-in-admin-panel-magento. By enabling the template path hint for admin panel you can see the path. if you have problem then you can ask